# Dapper not throwing an exception when select query does not contain expected column

Tags: ado.net, mapping, dapper

When using Dapper as follows:

```
connection.Query("select a from Foo").Select(x => new Foo(x.a, x.b));
```

My preference is that an exception is thrown when trying to access x.b, rather than it just returning null.

I understand that just returning null may be by design (e.g. for performance reasons), and ideally tests would exist that flag up the missing data, but if I could have both, this seems like an additional layer of safety that may be worth having.

Alternatively, is there another way to instantiate an object using a constructor in a way that will throw an exception when a needed column is missing?

Comment: Dapper do map your database output (DataReader) to your POCO. Thats it. So, if the field is not included in your `select` statement, value for respective property will be `null` or DEFAULT (0 for int; false for bool etc). How to handle this is up to you.

Comment: "what is the next most convenient library that would provide this behaviour?" this statement causes your question to be off-topic. Please edit the question.

Comment: "is there another way" Yes; there are multiple ways. You can implement `Check()` method in each poco that will check if it is filled up as you expect. If not, it will throw exception.

Comment: What `Check()` method could be implemented that would distinguish between a null due to a non-selected column, or a null due to a selected null value?

Comment: Dapper should be throwing a SqlException when used against a SqlConnection. Why not execute the the query then apply the select if there not an exception?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras Nope, no exception. I'm not really sure what you mean. The statement does execute the query then apply the select if there is no exception.

Answer (score -1):

Yup. Dapper often seems to err on the side of optimism. Every error is a runtime error, and as in this case, some things that you would like to be errors fly straight through.

Were you to use QueryFirst, you wouldn't even need to run the program. This would be caught as you type. You access your query results via generated POCOs, so if a column isn't in the query, it isn't in the POCO. If you use `select *`, then later delete a columnn from the DB, you can regenerate all your queries and the compile errors will point to the line in your code that tries to access the deleted column.

Download [here](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst).

Short video presentation [here](http://geniusorfantasist.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-tool-in-action.html).

disclaimer: I wrote QueryFirst